# return array of dates from a given range on specific days of the week with certain days excluded

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm trying to create a recursive function to produce an array of valid dates based on certain rules.

So far I've got this function

```
function progDateRange($date, $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded, $dates = array())
{
    $valid_date = false;
    $max_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $max_date->add(new DateInterval('P2Y'));
    $max_date = $max_date->format('Y-m-d');

    // is this date before the end date or the max date
    if(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date) && strtotime($date) <= strtotime($max_date))
    {
        if(!in_array($date, $excluded))
        {
            foreach($wkDays as $day => $val)
            {
                // is this date a valid weekday start
                if(date("l", strtotime($date)) == $day) {
                    // successful date
                    $valid_date = true;
                }
            }
            if($valid_date) {
                array_push($dates, $date);
            }
        }
        $next_day = new DateTime($date);
        $next_day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        progDateRange($next_day->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded, $dates);
    } else {
        return $dates;
    }
}
```

and I'm using it like so on a separate page

```
$datesArray = progDateRange($date_start, $date_end, $wkDays, $excluded);
```

I pass in a start date, an end date, an array of week days that valid dates occur on, and an array of dates to be excluded.

If I `print_r()` within the function like this

```
$next_day = new DateTime($date);
$next_day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
print_r($dates);
progDateRange($next_day->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded, $dates);
```

each loop does print out the array and keeps adding to it successfully, but for some reason when I try and `print_r($datesArray)` on the separate page nothing gets output not even a blank array, and I simply can't figure out why.

I'm sure it's going to be something silly, as the function appears to work for the most part, it's just stumbling at the point of returning the data.

What am I missing?

I've also just tried doing a `print_r()` just before the return statement, and this returns the exact array I'm trying to get my hands on. There's definitely something going wrong with the return/retrieve of the data on the page calling the function...

**edit**

As I didn't mention it earlier, here are example var dumps of `$wkDays` and `$excluded`

`$wkDays` produces

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Monday"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Tuesday"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Wednesday"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Thursday"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Friday"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Sunday"
}
```

and `$excludes` might be something like this

```
array(23) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2013-04-22"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2013-04-29"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2013-05-13"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2013-05-27"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2013-06-03"
  //...
}
```

an example call might go like this;

```
progDateRange("2013-05-01", "2017-05-01", array("Monday", "Wednesday"), array("2013-06-12", "2013-06-19"));
```

**SOLUTION**

After taking Jacks example, I had to make a couple of tweaks, and ended up with this;

```
function progDateRange($date, $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded)
{
    $dates = array();
    $todays_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $current_date = strtotime($date);
    $max_date = min(strtotime('+2 years'), strtotime($end_date));

    while ($current_date < $max_date)
    {
        if (!in_array($date, $excluded) && in_array(date('l', $current_date), $wkDays) && $current_date > $todays_date) {
            array_push($dates, $date);
        }
        $current_date = strtotime('+1 day', $current_date);
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $current_date);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: `$max_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 years'))` looks a lot easier than what you're doing now :) and why the recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `$dates` is not returned in the last recursive call, i.e. the function result is empty; that said, you don't even need recursion:

```
function progDateRange($date, $end_date, array $wkDays, array $excluded)
{
    $dates = array();

    $current_date = strtotime($date);
    $max_date = min(strtotime('+2 years'), strtotime($end_date));
    $dow = array_keys($wkDays);

    while ($current_date < $max_date) {
        if ($excluded && in_array($date_formatted, $excluded, true)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (in_array(date('l'), $dow, true)) {
            array_push($dates, $date);
        }
        $current_date = strtotime('+1 day', $current_date);
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $current_date);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this rewrite of the function, it didn't quite work as is, but with a little tweaking, I've got what I want and now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of the recursive call. Like this:

```
$dates = array_merge(
    $dates,
    progDateRange($next_day->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded, $dates)
);
```

Or, as you might already tried to do (it looks like), use $dates as a call by reference param. Note the `&` before the param name:

```
function progDateRange($date, $end_date, $wkDays, $excluded, &$dates = array())
```

But I would prefer the first approach

Comment: I had tried the second solution you mentioned, however again nothing was returned. The first solution puzzles me a bit though, I've never used += for anything other than adding to a variable, how would this work with an array?

Comment: [Array Operators - PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) But I see, the `+` doesn't fit here

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know. Unfortunately, when actually trying that, I get `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types...`. Your edited solution also returns blank...

Comment: `Your edited solution also returns blank.` what does this mean?

Comment: Btw, I see no reason for recursion here. I would redesign that function

Comment: by blank, i simply mean nothing gets returned, same as before.
I'm not aware of a way to achieve what I want without recursion. If you could point me in the right direction of a better way to produce this function I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Currently have no time for a deeper look. Maybe later

Comment: How does `$wkDays`,`$excluded` look like? Can you edit the question and a var_dumps of the them. A complete example how you call it would be great

Comment: I appreciate the time you put in to help me, so +1 for that!